# How to unit test unformatted method in mvc?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to unit test one of the very big and unformatted method in ASP.NET MVC 4.0.

Below is the code of action method :-

```
    public ActionResult GetDetails(string ProdName, int ProdArea, int ProdAreaId= 0)
    {
        if (ProdAreaId == 0 && ProdArea == 1 && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ResponseProdAreaId"] != null)
        {
            ProdAreaId = (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ResponseProdAreaId"];
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProdName))
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProdName"] == null)
            {
                ProdName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProdName"] = ProdName;
            }
            else
            {
                ProdName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ProdName"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ProdName = ProdName.Replace("___", " ");
        }


        List<StateDetail> stateList = ProductService.GetAllStates().Where(n => n.FKCountryID == (int)Countries.UnitedStates).ToList();

        ProductAddressViewModel model = new ProductAddressViewModel
        {
            ProdArea = ProdArea,
            FKProductID = CurrentProductId
        };

        model.States = stateList != null ? new SelectList(stateList, "StateID", "StateCode") : null;

        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[“ProdAddresses”] != null && ProdAreaId == 0 && ProdArea == 1)
        {
            List<ProductAddressDto> lstprodaddresses = (List<ProductAddressDto>)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[“ProdAddresses”];
            if (lstprodaddresses.Count > 0)
            {
                AddressDto addrDto = lstprodaddresses.First().Address;
                //save address in DB
                model.Address1 = addrDto.Address1;
                model.Address2 = addrDto.Address2;
                model.ProdArea = 1;
                model.City = addrDto.City;
                model.IsDefault = true;
                model.ProdName = model.ProdName;
                model.SelectedAddressTypeID = (int)AddressType.Street;
                model.ZIPCode = addrDto.ZIPCode;
                model.SelectedStateId = addrDto.FKStateID;
                model.AddressTypes = GetAddressTypes();
            }
        }
        else if (model.FKProductID > 0)
        {
            ToolDto tool = ToolService.GetToolDetails(model.FKProductID);

            if (ProdAreaId > 0)
            {
                model.AddressTypes = GetAddressTypes();
                ProductAddressDto prodaddr = tool.ToolAddresses.First(n => n.Tool_AddressID == ProdAreaId);
                model.Address1 = prodaddr.Address.Address1;
                model.Address2 = prodaddr.Address.Address2;
                model.City = prodaddr.Address.City;
                model.SelectedStateId = prodaddr.Address.FKStateID;
                model.ZIPCode = prodaddr.Address.ZIPCode;
                model.SelectedAddressTypeID = prodaddr.Address.FKAddressTypeID;
                model.IsDefault = prodaddr.IsDefault;
                model.FKAddressID = prodaddr.FKAddressID;
                model.Tool_AddressID = prodaddr.Tool_AddressID;
                model.FKProductID = prodaddr.FKProductID;
                model.AddressTypes = GetAddressTypes();
            }
            else
            {
                //address types
                List<int> excludeAddrTypes = new List<int>();
                foreach (ProductAddressDto prodadrdto in tool.ToolAddresses)
                {
                    if (prodadrdto.Tool_AddressID != ProdAreaId)
                    {
                        excludeAddrTypes.Add(prodadrdto.Address.FKAddressTypeID);
                    }
                }
                if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[“ProdAddresses”] != null)
                {
                    excludeAddrTypes.Add((int)AddressType.Street);
                }

                var addrtypes = from AddressType e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AddressType))
                                where !excludeAddrTypes.Contains((int)e)
                                select new { Id = (int)e, Name = e.ToString() };

                model.AddressTypes = addrtypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = x.Name
                });
                if (tool.ToolAddresses.Count == 0)
                {
                    model.IsDefault = (ProdArea == 1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //filter out address types if responsed tool is there
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[“ProdAddresses”] != null)
            {
                List<int> excludeAddrTypes = new List<int>();
                excludeAddrTypes.Add((int)AddressType.Street);
                var addrtypes = from AddressType e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AddressType))
                                where !excludeAddrTypes.Contains((int)e)
                                select new { Id = (int)e, Name = e.ToString() };
                model.AddressTypes = addrtypes.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = x.Name
                });
            }
            else
            {
                model.AddressTypes = GetAddressTypes();
            }
            model.IsDefault = (ProdArea == 1);
        }
        model.ProdName = ProdName;
        return PartialView("_AddUpdateAddress", model);
    }
```

> > May be the method is not in correct format.But i have to do it's unit testing.I have do that in several different ways.But i am not sure about its correctness.
> >     I want to know that how should we do unit test for such a big and unformatted method like this.

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Below is the piece of code of my unit testing method :-

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetDetailsTest_NotEmpty()
    {                      
        var ProdName = random.ToString();
        var ProdArea = random.Next();
        var ProdAreaId = 0;

        var _toolServiceMock = new Mock<IToolService>();
        var _lookupServiceMock = new Mock<ILookupService>();

        var stateList = new List<StateDto> { 
            new StateDto() { StateID = random.Next(), StateCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Description = random.ToString(), FKCountryID = 1 },
            new StateDto() { StateID = random.Next(), StateCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Description = random.ToString(), FKCountryID = random.Next() },
        };

            _lookupServiceMock.Setup(s => s.GetAllStates()).Returns(stateList); // .Returns(stateList);

        //Arrange
        CustomerDto cust = _toolService.LookupCustomers("", "").FirstOrDefault();
        if (cust != null)
        {
            ToolDto tool = _toolService.GetToolDetails(cust.Tool.toolId);
            if (tool.ToolAddresses.Count > 0 && tool.ToolAddresses.First().Address != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["FKToolID"] = cust.FKToolID;

                var controller = new ToolController(_toolServiceMock.Object);

                PartialViewResult result = controller.SelectAddress(cust.Tool.Name, 1, tool.ToolAddresses.First().Tool_AddressID) as PartialViewResult;
                var viewmodel = (ToolAddressViewModel)((ViewResultBase)(result)).Model;
                if (viewmodel != null)
                {
                    //Act                    
                    Assert.AreEqual(tool.ToolAddresses.First().Address.Address1, viewmodel.Address1);
                    Assert.AreEqual("_AddUpdateAddress", result.ViewName);
                    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(viewmodel, typeof(ToolAddressViewModel));
                }

                //Act
                _lookupServiceMock.VerifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Start by defining the expected behavior you want to test.

Comment: If the method is too big, it is really hard to test it. The test would become something between a unit test and an integration test. Rather refactor it to something testable. Use integration tests to make sure you did not break anything.

Comment: Agree with the above. With so much going on in your controller action you can't test this as a unit - plus what is your test *actually* verifying. You need refactor and lose the hard dependencies you have on HttpContext/Session if you truly want to make this testable.

Comment: I agree with the comments above. The action method is far too long and complicated. I recommend that you keep your actions short and concise; offloading domain logic to services/repositories that you inject into your controller's constructor. By doing this your actions will be easy to test, and the domain logic can also be tested easier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your method is a way too complicated and too long.
Make your actions short and with one responsability to respect SOLID principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).
It will make your methods easier to test.

To help you with your problem, you can do something quick with your code :

- Split your actions in internal virtual methods with one concern each (internal to be testable in you unit test project, virtual to be able to mock them).
- Put the [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestAssembly")] on your controller
- In your unit test project, you will be able to test any of your internal methods separately.
- Finally, to test your action, use a mocking framework (RhinoMock, Moq) to mock all your internal virtual methods and test the logic of your action (proxies generated by mocking framework will let you mock virtual methods).

It's the easiest way you can test your logic without breaking the existing application.
The inconvenient is that your logic is in internal methods wich let the whole assembly able to use it.